# Application Validation gives an error

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Im redy to upload an ios app to apstore. Im using xcode 5. After archiving when I try to validate the archive it gives this error. Please tell me how to solve this

This is the error that Im getting

[image]

And this how I set the background modes for audion in my `info.plist` file

[image]

Please help me...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this link,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22

This contain information about different background modes keys.

Also you already included the audio playing mode in the first line, which is valid and the last one is not a background mode, so remove that one and it will work.

Also provide 120 by 120 px icon which is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,, But in this tutorial if we want to play audio in background it says we have to set that keyword http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios Im using AVPlayer to play music from urls

Comment: yes you are right, but in that tutorial he was using xcode 4.6 and now the keys are changed i guess in xocde 5 and iOS 7. the keys are also shown in this link.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20